# EGit not able to exclude /bin?

Tags: android, egit

I use `EGit` with `Eclipse 4`. Works fine so far. But when I try to configure an `Android` project to work with `EGit`, I have problems with the `.gitignore`: I'm not able to exclude the `/bin` branch from `Git`. No matter whether I edit `.gitignore` or use the UI interface.

I know that you have to `show` the files for exclusion, so to change the `Filter...` view to show hidden files and empty directories (like assets in this project).

But whatever I do, the `/bin` is not excludeable for `EGit`. It gets the Star Icon before Commit, and will be included.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Try adding "bin/" to your .gitignore and then refreshing the project.

Comment: Are you sure that you have not accidentally committed the `bin` folder? You can try to remove the `bin` folder and see if the removed files show up in the "Unstaged Changes" table of the Git Staging view.

Comment: @Mohit Adding "bin/" (instead of "/bin") did not work.

Comment: @robinst the problem occures even before the first commit.

Answer (score 3):

I had an issue with things in the `.gitignore` file not being ignored (using Egit and Eclipse). It turns out that files already in the index when they are added to the `.gitignore` file will not be ignored, nor the directories they are in. This is true even if they have never been committed. New files added to these directories *will* be ignored. Refreshing the project doesn't help, but once they are removed from the index, they automatically become ignored, as will the entire directory. Adding `bin/` as a line in the `.gitignore` (in the root directory of the project\repository) should work to exclude any `bin` (sub-directory at or below the `.gitignore` level) should work, but not if the files are in the index or have ever been committed.

There is also some odd behavior if you delete a directory when a file under it has been added to the index but not committed. It remains in the commit box.

Comment: So one solution could be to copy a `.gitignore` (e.g. from another project) to the new project _before_ activating EGit on it? I'll try :) Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

I found two workarounds:

1) After sharing the project, I do not add all files (by clicking Team/Add to index on the project), but add all subdirectories (like src and res) and all relevant files (like androidmanifest.xml). This way, EGit never wants to include /bin and /gen.

2) After adding everything, on the first commit I uncheck all the "bin" files. Interestingly, after the first commit, I can exclude bin by Team / remove from index" then, no matter that the bin files are not checked in.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

1. Disable automatical build
2. Delete bin and gen folder
3. Commit and push changes to delete bin and gen on remote repository
4. Build project manually
5. Maybe remove folders from index and add them to gitignore
6. Commit and push changes
7. Enable automatic build, if you want to

Answer (score 0):

First off, I've seen the following cause problems when collaboratively using Egit:
    /bin
    /gen

The first problem is that cleaning a project regenerates the files in those folders, which then looks like a new commit is required. Since it's annoying to commit again just because these files changed, I wanted to ignore the folder. The second problem is that these files are regenerated on each team member's computer and, again, new commits are required.

To avoid having to commit every time a project is cleaned, ignore those folders. This also happens to be the answer for this post's question.

To delete these folders and stop tracking follow the procedure below inside of Eclipse; it always works for me!

1. Right-click on project -> Team ->Commit (MAKE SURE TO SELECT ALL)
2. Project tab in window -> Deselect "Build Automatically"
3. Right-click on /gen -> Team -> ignore
4. Right-click on /gen -> Team -> remove from index
5. Do 3-4 for /bin
6. Right-click on project -> Team -> Commit (MAKE SURE TO SELECT ALL)
7. Project tab in window ->Select "build automatically"
8. Project will rebuild and regenerate the missing folders
9. Right-click on project -> Team ->Commit (there should only be a .classpath file to add)
10. That should be it!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The automatic build files such as bin and gen can work against egit's two-pase commit mechanism. They get tracked for commit before you can ignore them.

As previously mentioned, just turn off autobuild and delete anything you do not want in the repo. Commit these deletions to permanently remove them. I think that is where the confusion lies - deletions must be committed or the files forever remain in the repo.

When anything reappears during autobuild, git-ingore it so it will not be tracked for commit. Git's two-phase commit is rather low level, but that is it's strength. Overcoming eclipse autobuild this way is proof. Notice this problem does not involve loss of tracking, but rather too much tracking!

Answer (score 0):

If "Preferences > Team > Git > Projects > Automatically ignore derived resources" is switched on EGit should automatically add entries for resources generated by the build to .gitignore